# ld: library not found for -lgcc_ext.10.5

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm trying to compile a basic C++ program for school and when I try running it from the Mac Terminal (10.7.6), I get this message:

```
ld: library not found for -lgcc_ext.10.5
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm definitely in the correct directory and installed XCode Command Line tools. Here is my command prompt:

```
g++ -o chapter_2 hello_world.cpp
```

Here is my basic c++ program.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

  cout << "Hello world" << endl;

}
```

Comment: does libgcc_ext.10.5.* exist on the system?

Answer (score 2):

As Judd pointed out, the issue is that the linker can't find libgcc_ext.10.5. While I don't have an ideal solution for this, what worked for me was installing gcc-4.8 using [homebrew](http://brew.sh/), and using a newer gcc.

```
brew install gcc48
```

I believe there is even gcc49 now. Using this I was able to compile without problems (though note that I had to use `$ gcc-4.8 ...` in the console, as `$ gcc ...` still points to the older gcc version (unless you explicitly  change that).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, on OS X 10.8, with both current XCode and gcc installed by Homebrew.

When I checked `$ which g++` it gave `/usr/local/bin/g++`.

So I commented this path in `.bash_profile`:

```
#PATH="/usr/local/bin:${PATH}"
```

Now `$ which g++` gives `/usr/bin/g++` and its version indicates that it is from XCode and there is no `ld: library not found for -lgcc_ext.10.5` error.

Comment: I was having a similar problem, and this worked for me. Just remember to uncomment that line in .bash_profile after you're done or you won't have access to anything you've installed with homebrew.

Comment: Worked for me.  C compile issues will never get old.  You can make a living just from knowing c compilers and not even writing C code :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a mac guy, but I recognize the issue is that the linker can't find the library, (libgcc_ext.10.5) because your development environment is incorrectly set up. I would expect it to be in /usr/lib or /usr/local/lib or something to that effect. You might try doing a `ld --help` and see if you can find out how the linker search path is specified. (ld is the program that does the linking, g++ calls it when it is done compiling.) Then find the library on your machine and add that path to the ld search path.