# Still Unresolved: "ld: library not found for -lgcc_ext.10.5"

Tags: macos, gcc, homebrew

I've seen this question asked elsewhere but AFAIK nobody has posted a definitive response. So, how does one resolve the following:

```
ld: library not found for -lgcc_ext.10.5
```

I'm using HomeBrew on Mac OS X 10.11.1 (El Capitan)

Thanks!

Comment: what did you try to install?

Comment: I bet you've looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694912/ld-library-not-found-for-lgcc-ext-10-5) question?

Comment: @Srgrn I'm trying to compile a simple hello world using 'make'

Comment: @Thomas Yes, I have, but I'm looking for a permanent fix, not a temporary solution. Just updated gcc, version is now 5.1.0.

Comment: @user913304 first of all why you are trying to use `GCC` on OSX instead of `Clang`?

Comment: I would guess that like on my own machine G++ is the xcode g++ and not gcc. you can set your path to include gcc before /usr/bin. what about http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99077/how-to-set-gcc-4-8-as-default-gcc-compiler

Comment: @Srgrn I tried all of the suggestions there and I'm still getting "ld: library not found for -lgcc_ext.10.5"

Comment: if you supply a makefile or something i can try i might be able to help more